# apple watch itunes store operation failed Apple Watch app submission

Tags: ios, iphone, watchkit, apple-watch

i am trying to submit the app on itune with apple watch extension. when i validate the ipa  i got errors

1. your app contains non-public API  usage. please review the error, correct them and resubmit your app.
2. the app links non-public Library in payload //plugins. watchkit Extension.appex/Watchkit App.app/_watchkitStub/WK:System/ Libraby/ privateFrameworks/ SockPuppetGizmo.frameworks/SockPuppetGizmo

3.the app links non-public Library in WatchKitSuuport/WK:System/ Libraby/ privateFrameworks/ SockPuppetGizmo.frameworks/SockPuppetGizmo

Comment: Well seems like they don't want you to use 3rd Party Libraries. In this case obviously *SockPuppetGizmo*

Comment: @LinusG SockPuppetGizmo is not a third-party library, but one of Apple's own private libraries, which in this case is pretty obvious from the error message.